# can anyone think of a way to fix this

Tags: vb.net, console

I have made this code which is used to encrypt/decrypt a word using two keywords, my encryption works but my decrypt doesn't. i would really appreciate if someone would tell me how to change it
here are the two.

```
 Sub encryption()
    Dim plain As String
    Dim keyword As String
    Dim keyword2 As String     ' declares these as variables(text)
    Dim encoded_message() As String


    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red

    Console.Write("Enter your plaintext: ")
    plain = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()      'stores input into plain variable and converts it into upper case

    Console.Write("Enter your keyword: ")
    keyword = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()     'stores input into keyword variable and converts it into upper case

    Console.Write("Enter your second keyword: ")
    keyword2 = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()     'stores input into keyword2 variable and converts it into upper case

    While plain.Length > keyword.Length
        keyword = keyword + keyword      'keyword cipher needs to make the keyword same length as the plaintext
    End While

    While plain.Length > keyword2.Length
        keyword2 = keyword2 + keyword2
    End While


    keyword = Asc(keyword)        'finds out ascii value of keyword

    keyword2 = Asc(keyword2)    'finds out ascii value of keyword2
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta

    Console.WriteLine("here is your encrypted message")

    ReDim Preserve encoded_message(0 To plain.Length - 1)
    For stepper As Integer = 0 To plain.Length - 1
        encoded_message(stepper) = Asc(plain(stepper)) + keyword + keyword2 - 96
        Console.Write(Chr(encoded_message(stepper)))

    Next
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

   Sub decrytpion()
    Dim plain As String
    Dim keyword As String
    Dim keyword2 As String
    Dim encoded_message() As Integer

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red

    Console.Write("Enter your plaintext: ")
    plain = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()

    Console.Write("Enter your keyword: ")
    keyword = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()

    Console.Write("Enter your second keyword: ")
    keyword2 = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()

    While plain.Length > keyword.Length
        keyword = keyword + keyword
    End While

    While plain.Length > keyword2.Length
        keyword2 = keyword2 + keyword2
    End While

    keyword = Asc(keyword)        'finds out ascii value of keyword

    keyword2 = Asc(keyword2)    'finds out ascii value of keyword2

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta

    Console.WriteLine("here is your decrypted message")

    ReDim Preserve encoded_message(0 To plain.Length - 1)
    For stepper As Integer = 0 To plain.Length - 1
        encoded_message(stepper) = Asc(plain(stepper)) - keyword - keyword2 + 96
        Console.Write(Chr(encoded_message(stepper)))

    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Without commenting on the robustness of this, the specific issue is that your encoding can produce lower case characters as output but when you read back that data to decode it you force them all to be upper case: `plain = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()` which completely changes their values.

Remove `ToUpper` and it will behave as you expect.